# Conflict between action and onsubmit of a form

Tags: javascript, forms, action, settimeout, onsubmit

I am developing an application in python Flask. I have a form, on click of which an action is triggered in order to execute a part in app.py. However I want the button to be clickable only once in 24 hours. So I tried to implement the onsubmit event. But since the onsubmit gets executed first I have problems with the action part relating to the code in app.py getting executed.

1)This is the form code:

```
 <form name="Update" action="/update" method="post">
    <input type="submit" id="myBtn" value="Update" onsubmit="myFunction()">
 </form>`
```

2)The action='/update" triggers this part in app.py:

```
@app.route('/update',methods=['POST'])
def Update():
 ....
 ....
 ....
return render_template('index.html', output=output)
```

3)The code I tried to enable timeout for the form submit which caused the conflict.

```
<script>
  function myFunction() 
  {
    document.getElementById("myBtn").disabled = true;
    setTimeout(function()
    {
      document.getElementById("myBtn").disabled = false;
    }, 200000);
  }
</script>
```

Since document.getElementById("myBtn").disabled = true; is hitting first the action part is not getting executed. Please provide an assistance on how to approach this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You may try to place "onsubmit" to form rather than input.

```
<form name="Update" action="/update" method="post" onsubmit="myFunction()">
    <input type="submit" id="myBtn" value="Update">
</form>
```

js part

```
<script>
  function myFunction() 
  {
      return true; /// form execution goes on
      return false; /// form execution stops
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I tried placing "onsubmit" to form but what should be my js part be in order to make the button clickable only once in 24 hours.

Comment: I will think on that too. However as a first impression, JS approach can not be reliable since it is on client side. For instance, if you check the time on client it would be their local time..